# Current database schema and generated classes compatibility (Propel ORM)

Tags: php, database, orm, propel

Does PropelORM have a way to verify current database schema's compatibility with all generated classes?

The point is that if the generated classes have fields or tables that do not have database schema, output an error message before an internal Propel error ocurs.

PS: The try-catch block is not suitable for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ["migrations"](http://propelorm.org/documentation/09-migrations.html) to check if your current schema matches the database.